# Получение текста с кнопки

Tags: java, android

Нужно получить текст, написанный на кнопке, из события:

```
public void onClick1(View v)
{

}
```

Comment: String text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();

Comment: @woesss описал более правильное решение

Comment: @woesss Перенесите, пожалуйста, свой комментарий в ответ для этого вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае желательно еще проверять тип объекта, а то мало ли:

```
public void onClick1(View v)
{
    if(v == null || !(v instanceof TextView)) {
        return; //нет свойства text
    }

    String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
}
```

В данном примере кода проверяем, что `v` не `null` (вдруг мы вызвали метод программно с `null`) и что `v` есть объект класса `TextView` (именно у `TextView` есть свойство `text`), это актуально, если вдруг окажется, что событие пришло от `ImageButton`, у которой текста нет.

Comment: Вот это некропост. Вопрос сам по себе дурацкий его удалить надо.